# Как узнать, в каком браузере работает пользователь?

Tags: gwt, java

Работаю с GWT. Посмотрел методы [Window.Navigator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Navigator.html), но ни один не возвращает браузер пользователя. Мне нужно узнать, использует ли пользователь Safari. Как это сделать в GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [Deferred Binding](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html). Это почти наверняка позволит вам сделать то, что сам надо.

А чем вас [Window.Navigator.getUserAgent()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Navigator.html#getUserAgent%28%29) не устраивает? Там ведь будет видно, о каком браузере идёт речь...

Comment: Там очень много всего написано, а не только имя браузера + версия. :(

Comment: Парсите товарищ)

Comment: Так там указано сразу несколько браузеров!

Comment: значение этого параметра имеет глубокие исторические корни, но определенный формат все же есть, посмотрите хотя бы http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent.

Comment: И всё же я советую Deferred Binding. Он решает подобные проблемы на раз.

Answer (score 1):

В свое время эта проблема была решена так:

```
public static BrowserType getBrowserType() {
        String browserName = getBrowserTypeString();
        BrowserType result;
        if (browserName.indexOf("msie 7.0") != -1) {
            result = BrowserType.INTERNET_EXPLORER_7;
        } else if (browserName.indexOf("msie 6.0") != -1) {
            result = BrowserType.INTERNET_EXPLORER_6;
        } else if (browserName.indexOf("msie") != -1) {
            result = BrowserType.INTERNET_EXPLORER_OTHER;
        }else  if (browserName.indexOf("gecko") != -1) {
            result = BrowserType.MOZILLA_FIREFOX;
        } else if (browserName.indexOf("opera") != -1) {
            result = BrowserType.OPERA;
        } else if (browserName.indexOf("webkit") != -1) {
            result = BrowserType.SAFARI;
        } else {
            result = BrowserType.UNDEFINED;
        }
        return result;
}

private static native String getBrowserTypeString() /*-{
        return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
}-*/;

public static enum BrowserType{
    MOZILLA_FIREFOX,
    INTERNET_EXPLORER_6,
    INTERNET_EXPLORER_7,
    INTERNET_EXPLORER_OTHER,
    OPERA,
    SAFARI,
    UNDEFINED
}
```

Comment: 1.Ваш код покажет, что Хром - это Сафари, 2.Зачем здесь нативный код, если есть Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().toLowerCase()!

Answer (score 1):

Можете посмотреть, как это сделано в [com.google.gwt.dev.util.BrowserInfo](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/util/BrowserInfo.java)

Comment: >Зачем здесь нативный код, если есть Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().toLowerCase()

Ну не страшно - семантика та же.

> com.google.gwt.dev.util.BrowserInfo
То что есть стандартная реализация - это хорошо.

У нас в проекте этот код используется уже достаточно давно (GWT 2.0 насколько я помню ещё не было и Chrome только появился) и нам необходимо было различать версии Internet Explorer'а.
> Хром - это Сафари

Так правильно - у них [движок-то][1] один 

[1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit